# Выползающий блок при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: html, jquery, css

есть див 1

есть див 2

див 1 - display:block

див 2 - display: none

Мне нужно реализовать такую штуку: при щелчке по див1 у див2 display меняется на block. При повторном щелчке, обратно становится none.

Как это реализовать? не важно скриптом или css.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function stateChange() {
  var obj = document.getElementById('2');

  obj.style.display = 
      (obj.style.display == "none" ?
      "block" : "none");
}
```

```html
<div id=1 onclick="stateChange()">First div</div>
<div id=2 style="display : none">Second div</div>
```

Comment: VenZell, благодарен

Answer (score 2):

Если jQuery, то можно так:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#div1").click(function(){
        $("div#div2").toggle(); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

<div id="div1" style="display: block;">Первый DIV</div>
<div id="div2" style="display: none;">Второй DIV</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, ваше решение сработало и помогло мне организовать выползающее меню на сайте. Теперь стоит такая задача: как сделать так, чтобы на главной странице это меню изначально было показано, а на всех страницах спрятано?

Comment: @ЯковАлександрович, к  меню на главной `style="display: block"`