# Как сделать плавное выдвижение блока Jquery?

Tags: jquery, меню

Сделал менюшку, выдвигающуюся при нажатии на кнопку с помощью такого кода:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div#div1").click(function() {
    $("div#div2").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" style="display : block">Первый DIV</div>
<div id="div2" style="display : none">Второй DIV</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы она выдвигалась плавно?

Comment: Интересно, вы так и будете решения предыдущего вопроса [Выползающий блок при нажатии на кнопку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424014/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83) переносить в новый вопрос вместо того, чтобы разобраться в решении, почитать документацию хотя бы?

Comment: прошу прощение за мое тугодумство. я здесь недавно и еще не вполне разобрался со здешними правилами. А документацию рою - правда ничего в ней не понимаю ) Сегодня весь день потратил на решение этого вопрова. Хотя для специалиста, как видно, работы на минуту )

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div#div1").click(function() {
    $("div#div2").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" style="display : block">Первый DIV</div>
<div id="div2" style="display : none">Второй DIV</div>
```

Comment: .slideToggle(); должен помочь!

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div#div1").click(function() {
    $("div#div2").slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

По-моему еще можно для `slideToggle('400')` - задать в миллисекундах

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй через `.mouseenter()` и `.mouseleave` [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/7RFDH/230/)

```js
$('.cont').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.cont2').slideToggle(500);
});
$('.cont').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.cont2').slideToggle(500);
});
```

```css
.cont {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #222;
}
.cont2 {
display:none;
height:60px;
position:relative;
}
.cs{
     position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
.block {
 background: #222;
 position: relative;
 width: 100px; height: 50px;
}
.block::after {
 content: ''; 
 position: absolute;
 right: 40px; top: -20px;
 border: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div href="#" class="cont">
  </div>
  <div class="cont2"><div class="cs"><div class="block"></div></div>
  </div>
</body>
```